# Recursive function in R to find unique rows of a list of data tables

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a function that takes a list of data tables with the same column names as an input and returns a single data table that has the unique rows from each data frame combined using successive rbind as shown below.

The function would be applied on a "very" large data.table (10s of millions of rows) which is why I had to split it up into several smaller data tables and assign them into a list to use recursion. At each step depending upon the length of the list of data tables (odd or even), I find the unique of data.table at that list index and the data table at the list index x - 1 and then successively rbind the 2 and assign to list index x - 1, and more list index x.

I must be missing something obvious, because although I can produce the final unique-d data.table when I print it (eg., print (listelement[[1]]), when I return (listelement[[1]]) I get NULL. Would help if someone can spot what I am missing ... or suggest if there is perhaps any other more efficient way to perform this.

Also, instead of having to add each data.table to a list, can I add them as "references" in the list ? I believe doing something like list(datatable1, datatable2 ...) would actually copy them ?

```
## CODE
returnUnique2 <- function (alist) {

if (length(alist) == 1) {
  z <- (alist[[1]])
  print (class(z))
  print (z)   ### This is the issue, if I change to return (z), I get NULL (?)
}

if (length(alist) %% 2 == 0) {
  alist[[length(alist) - 1]] <- unique(rbind(unique(alist[[length(alist)]]), unique(alist[[length(alist) - 1]])))
  alist[[length(alist)]] <- NULL
  returnUnique2(alist)
}

if (length(alist) %% 2 == 1 && length(alist) > 2) {
  alist[[length(alist) - 1]] <- unique(rbind(unique(alist[[length(alist)]]), unique(alist[[length(alist) - 1]])))
  alist[[length(alist)]] <- NULL
  returnUnique2(alist)
}  
}


## OUTPUT with print statement
t1 <- data.table(col1=rep("a",10), col2=round(runif(10,1,10)))
t2 <- data.table(col1=rep("a",10), col2=round(runif(10,1,10)))
t3 <- data.table(col1=rep("a",10), col2=round(runif(10,1,10)))
tempList <- list(t1, t2, t3)

returnUnique2(tempList)

[1] "list"
[[1]]
col1 col2
 1:    a    3
 2:    a    2
 3:    a    5
 4:    a    9
 5:    a   10
 6:    a    7
 7:    a    1
 8:    a    8
 9:    a    4
10:    a    6
```

Changing the following,

```
print (z)   ### This is the issue, if I change to return (z), I get NULL (?)
```

to read

```
return(z)
```

returns NULL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using `sqlite` for this size of data?

Comment: Hi Karsten, Thanks, I tried that, but still too slow ... am using fread to read in the data in csv format and seems it is faster than sqlite. Also the motivation behind using it this way is that I have several other datasets which I am offloading to individual cores on the server using the doParallel/multicore packages.

Comment: Was the below any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstand what you're doing, but it sounds like you have one big `data.table` and are trying to split it up to run some function on it and would then combine everything back and run a unique on that. The `data.table` way of doing that would be to use `by`, e.g.

```
fn = function(d) {
  # do whatever to the subset and return the resulting data.table
  # in this case, do nothing
  d
}

N = 10  # number of pieces you like
dt[, fn(.SD), by = (seq_len(nrow(dt)) - 1) %/% (nrow(dt)/N)][, seq_len := NULL]
dt = dt[!duplicated(dt)]
```

Comment: I think they literally *just* want to get the unique rows in the `data.table`, i.e. the last line!

Comment: @SimonO101 ok, I thought the other problem of OP was that the initial data was too large and they decided to split it, put it in a list and do operations on small pieces, which is something that can be done with much less trouble as shown above

Comment: HI Simon, Eddi, the above is perfect for what I was intending to do. Main thing was I was trying to avoid the for loop and this achieves that quite gracefully. Thanks to all for the help with this issue ! The data table in question has >1 billion rows and it takes ages for even fread to even start parsing the file. So, I had to use unix split to split this file and then process sequentially. Otherwise, I could have run unique on the whole dataset at once, but in this case, that was not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this could be a good use case for a `for` loop. With many rows the overhead of using a `for` loop should be relatively small compared to the computation time. I would try combining my `data.table`'s into a list (called `ll` in my example), then for each one remove duplicated rows, then `rbind` to the previous `data.table` with unique rows and then subset by unique rows again.

If you have many duplicated rows in each chunk then this might save some time, overall I'm not sure how effective it will be, but worth a shot?

```
#  Create empty data.table for results (I have columns x and y in this case)
res <- data.table( x= numeric(0),y=numeric(0))

#   loop over all data.tables in a list called 'll'
for( i in 1:length(ll) ){
    #  rbind the unique rows from the current list element to the results from all previous iterations
    res <- rbind( res , ll[[i]][ ! duplicated(ll[[i]]) , ] )
    #  Keep only unique records at each iteration
    res <- res[ ! duplicated(res) , ]
}
```

On another note, have you looked at the documentation for `data.table`? It explicitly states,

> Because data.tables are usually sorted by key, tests for duplication
>   are especially quick.

So you might just be better off running on the entire data.table?

```
DT[ ! duplicated(DT) , ]
```

Comment: Another option would be to split the data into 2s and rbind them recursively. For eg., if I had 8 chunks - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 instead of performing unique rbind incrementally, I could get rbind of unique of (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) and then rbind them again in 2s. Could be more efficient that incremental rbinds.

Comment: @xbsd sure that might be a bit more efficient. I guess that's a design decision. The effectiveness would depend on the 'uniqueness' or not of successive chunks. But how slow is just using the last line in practice? 10 milliseconds? 10 seconds? 10 hours?

Comment: Hi Simon, I believe using just the last line could be quite fast, the issue is that loading the entire dataset and then running the unique would use up a lot of memory and might lead to slowdown, not due to the operation, but more at a hardware load level. Splitting them in chunks, running unique, gc() at each iteration, and gradually cutting down the dataset size seems to be a faster option. I have tried this using foreach and dopar across 4 cores on a Mac and it was much faster using a 10m row dataset compared to a single unique operation.

Comment: @SimonO101 a small (and irrelevant to OP) thing to keep in mind (that will reduce a little bit of clutter) is that the comma after the `i-expression` is not necessary when working with data.tables when you don't have a `j`

Comment: @eddi thanks for for pointing that out. I didn't know that, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id column to each data.table

```
t1$id=1
t2$id=2
t3$id=3
```

then combine them all at once and do a unique using `by=`.
If the data.tables are huge you could use setkey(...) to create an index on id before calling unique.

```
tall=rbind(t1,t2,t3)
tall[,unique(col1,col2),by=id]
```

Comment: I need the unique of all the data tables combined, ... Not per data table in the list, ... Computationally, running an unique on a table which has 100 million rows would take forever compared to a chunking split-apply unique - combine - repeat type strategy.